# How to access success data out of success block in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("uniquerheading", function(value, element) {     
        var data = false;
        $action_name = 'checkunquieannoucementheading';

        var url = '<?php echo "$module_name/$controller_name/checkunquieannoucementheading"; ?>';
        $.ajax({
             url: url,
             type: 'get',
             data: {
                "txt_heading":value             
             },
             success: function(data) {              
                // Display list on the page by replacing the content on existing, get from the controller-action
                return data;
             }
        });


}, "Annoucement heading already used");
```

Comment: What's wrong with data.myProperty?

Comment: The function is not return the data ..always return false

Comment: you can't use it because this only used to return true or false.

Comment: I want to same return true or false but its not updating false...It remain false always whatever the response

Comment: @Pramod does request passed to desired url.??

Comment: Every thing is fine ..only response is not affecting from data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Code...Just use async:   false

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("uniquerheading", function(value, element) { 

        $action_name = 'checkunquieannoucementheading';
        var response = false;
        var url = '<?php echo "$module_name/$controller_name/checkunquieannoucementheading"; ?>';
            $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'get',
            data: {
                    "txt_heading":value             
            },
            success: function(data) {               
                // Display list on the page by replacing the content on existing, get from the controller-action
                response =  data;
            },
            async:   false
        })

        return response;

}, "Annoucement heading already used");
```